# how to create a list of duplicated items between two lists using list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

The script is supposed to create a list of string elements which are people's names via user input and greet them if they're in the vip list. I tried to create a list with repeated elements between the list of names and the list of vips in order to store the new list in a variable `temp` so the greetings could be printed out. But it didn't work.

My attempt:
#!/usr/bin/python3

```
mylist = input("Enter list of names separated by comma: ").split(",")
vip = ['Tom', 'Howard', 'Alice', 'Peter', 'Maria']

temp = [x for x in vip if x in mylist]

print([f"Hello {myvar}!" for myvar in temp])
```

current behaviour with user input `'Alice, Robert, Maria, Peter, Jen'` :

```
['Hello Alice!']
```

expected behaviour:

```
['Hello Alice!', 'Hello Maria!', 'Hello Peter!']
```

Comment: `split(', ')` instead of `split(',')`

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to use regex here, `re.split(r" *, *", mylist)` (these names have spaces after splitting on `,`!), however, always remember [falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). This breaks on `"Sammy Davis, Jr."`.

Comment: Alternatively you can call `strip()` on the values after you split them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to make few changes in the code. One is split(", ").
The other is in list comprehension.

```
mylist = input("Enter list of names separated by comma: ").split(", ")

vip = ['Tom', 'Howard', 'Alice', 'Peter', 'Maria']

temp = [name for name in mylist if name in vip]

print([f"Hello {myvar}!" for myvar in temp])
```

Gives

```
['Hello Alice!', 'Hello Maria!', 'Hello Peter!']
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To followup on Mark M's comment:

```
mylist = [x.strip() for x in input("Enter list of names separated by comma: ").split(",")]
```